# How to utilize a URL regex match inside of the last grouping?

Tags: regex

This is my regex

```
(?:!\(([elementType | inlineType]+),([\w\d\s\#]+),([\w\d\s]+),([\w\d\s\-]+),([\s\w\d\.\:\/\-\_\?\=]+)\))
```

This regex has 5 groups separated by commas, where as the last one needs to match any URL. I'm having a bit difficulty with it as it doesn't seem like i can paste in a URL matcher that I find on the internet inside of it. It seems to only be matching one thing at a time.

Comment: There are a few things to note here, the `[...]` is a character class and `\w` also matches `\d` Perhaps something like `(?:!\(((?:element|inline)Type),([\w\s#]+),([\w\s]+),([\w\s-]+),(https?:\/\/\S+)\))` https://regex101.com/r/bhObA0/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird It has to match something like this. I don't believe its working for me. Also regarding the `\w` and `\d`, makes sense! Thank you

`!(block, foo, bar, foo-bar, https://www.google.com)`

Comment: It all depends on what you want to allow to match in the capture groups `!\(([\w#-]+),\s*([\ws#-]+),\s*([\w-]+),\s*([\w-]+),\s*(https?:\/\/\S+)\)` https://regex101.com/r/guiXeE/1

Answer (score 0):

Some notes about your pattern:

- `\w` also matches `\d`
- This notation is a character class `[elementType | inlineType]+` but as you also want to match block you can also use `\w` for that
- You don't have to escape these characters in a character class `.` `:` `_` `?` `=`

Using 5 capture groups, where the 5th one matches an url like pattern:

```
  !\(([\w#-]+),\s*([\w#-]+),\s*([\w-]+),\s*([\w-]+),\s*(https?:\/\/\S+)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `!` Match literally
- `\(` Match `(`
- `([\w#-]+),\s*([\w#-]+),\s*([\w-]+),\s*([\w-]+),\s*` 4 capture groups where the character class `[\w#-]+` matches 1+ occurrences of the allowed listed characters
- `(https?:\/\/\S+)` Capture group 5, match the protocol with an optional s, then `://` and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IrNGB2/1)